# Excel: Calculate the frequency of a particular month in a column of date cells

Tags: excel

I have a column with dates of events. ( let's say: A1:A100 )

Now I want to use a formula to find or display the number of events that occurred in January 2013.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an array formula, sometimes called "CSE" formulas because of the way you have to enter them:

Pick your destination cell and select it.
Then, in the formula bar, enter:

```
=SUM(IF((A1:A100>=DATEVALUE("1/1/2013"))*(A1:A100<=DATEVALUE("31/1/2013")),1,0))
```

And instead of [enter], press [ctrl]+[shift]+[enter]

I *really* don't understand why MS make you do the CSE thing- surely it's clear from the format that it's an array formula?

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Countifs` to find records between a `start and end date`? You can either type the dates or point it to two cells containing the dates. Not sure which version of Excel you are using, but `CountIfs` is not supported in 2003 but beyond.

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A100,">="&C2,A2:A100,"<="&C3)
```

or

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A100,">=1/1/2013",A2:A100,"<=31/1/2013")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FREQUENCY` formula together with an auxiliary `MONTH` function:

1. Enter the number 1-12 in your results table (e.g. in D1:D12)
2. Select the the twelve adjacent cells (in the example it would be E1:E12) and enter `=FREQUENCY(MONTH(A1:A1000),D1:D12)` - enter the formula as array formula (i.e. press `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` instead of `Enter`)

In case you want to also separate by years, you need to modify your keys in column D and your formula to derive the key, e.g. instead of `MONTH(A1:A1000)` you could use `MONTH(A1:A1000)&"-"&YEAR(A1:A1000)` - or (if purely used in an one Locale environment `TEXT(A1:A1000,"MM-YY")`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

- Use the SUMPRODUCT formula to summarize by month.  See example: http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions04.html#SumProduct
- Use a Pivot table:

  Add a column B `=month(a1)`.  Fill down.
  Add a column C of all `1`s.

  Give A, B, C header names:  `Date`, `Month`, `Count`.

  Insert a Pivot table based on A,B,C.  Now you can easily Sum by Month.
- A formula (if you know exactly which month you are looking for):

  Perhaps do a fill down in column B with a formula like this:
  `=if(and(month(a1)=1,year(a1)=2013),1,0)`, then `sum()` column B?
- Use Consolidate functionality.  Take a look at: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/use-consolidate-to-summarize-excel-data-without-sorting/6521

Comment: It's sort of my last resort solution. It would pretty messy since I need to do that 12 times ( for each months ). I know it would work, but I believe a solution might exist that would be "clean"...

Comment: Are you wanting a broader way to summarize the months represented in the dates in A1:A100.  I.e., you don't just want January 2013, you want to summarize all the month counts?

Comment: To get all the months and years with ease, list months (1..12) and years in one column (or row) and use references to these helper cells in formulae proposed. Then there will be no need to change the formula manually. The helper cells can be hidden.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think Consolidate is the way to go for you here.  You have to try it out a few times, if you haven't used it before, in order to "get" how to use it (at least I had to work at it).  I've added a link in the answer to a Consolidate example that helped me learn how to use it.

Comment: One other note.  Personally, I'd use a Pivot table, but that's just because I use them all day long.  If you are also comfortable with them, then maybe just do that?  If the learning curve has already been overcome--they are amazing.